# Folders not showing up in 'Recent' view in 14.04

Tags: nautilus, files, directory

If I open up what is now called files, and click on 'recent' in the left hand column, it gives me all the files I've used recently well enough, but none of the folders. Folders are how I keep everything organised and browse the system. Is there any way to get them to show up?